# How to view Jenkins jobs in ROS Index

Tags: ros2, jenkins

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am developing on an amd64 system and would like to be able to quickly see if there are binaries available for packages on other architectures (arm).

The ROS1 wiki has a handy section in the Package Links that shows all the Jenkins jobs, but I can't seem to find the same information in ROS Index for ROS2 packages.

How can I see what binaries are available for a ROS2 package?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/415772/how-to-view-jenkins-jobs-in-ros-index/) by [chives_onion](https://answers.ros.org/users/39292/chives_onion/) on ROS Answers with karma: 180 on 2023-05-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm pretty sure that doesn't exist at the moment, or I at least don't know of a direct analogue of what you refer to on the ROS 1 wiki. (Edit: would perhaps make for a nice contribution: the information is all there).

An alternative, but somewhat different, could be [repo.ros2.org/status_page](https://repo.ros2.org/status_page). These are also linked from the [Resources section](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Installation/Ubuntu-Install-Debians.html#resources) in the Humble Ubuntu installation documentation.

Those pages are periodically updated by the ROS 2 buildfarm, and provide basically the same information as the list you refer to on the ROS 1 wiki, but in a different format.

The names of the pages correspond to the platform/OS a particular ROS 2 version supports and gets packages built for. For Humble fi, there are:

- [ros_humble_default.html](https://repo.ros2.org/status_page/ros_humble_default.html): the "default" OS for Humble, being Ubuntu Jammy
- [ros_humble_rhel.html](https://repo.ros2.org/status_page/ros_humble_rhel.html): Humble on RedHat Enteprise Linux
- [ros_humble_ujv8.html](https://repo.ros2.org/status_page/ros_humble_ujv8.html): Humble on Ubuntu Jammy on ARMv8 (or `arm64`, as opposed to something like `armhf`)

If you open the first one, and filter for `rclcpp`, [you get this page](https://repo.ros2.org/status_page/ros_humble_default.html?q=rclcpp%24):

[image: image description]

The links to the buildfarm jobs are "hidden" in the last two columns: `Jsource` and `J64`. That would be the *source jobs* and the `amd64` binary jobs respectively. The squares can have different colours than green, and the page has a legend for what those other colours would mean which I won't duplicate here.

The first square in each column links you to a job. For `rclcpp` that would be:

- [Hsrc_uJ__rclcpp__ubuntu_jammy__source](https://build.ros2.org/view/Hsrc_uJ/job/Hsrc_uJ__rclcpp__ubuntu_jammy__source): the source job for `rclcpp` in Humble, on Ubuntu Jammy
- [Hbin_uJ64__rclcpp__ubuntu_jammy_amd64__binary](https://build.ros2.org/view/Hbin_uJ64/job/Hbin_uJ64__rclcpp__ubuntu_jammy_amd64__binary): the binary job building `rclcpp` in Humble, for Ubuntu Jammy on `amd64`

For other supported platforms/OS, you'd have to open the other pages under `repos.ros2.org/status_page`.

Or perhaps you could navigate to the source job and check what *Downstream Projects* exist:

[image: image description]

As yet another alternative: that same host also serves `.yaml` files which contain the same/similar information: [repo.ros2.org/status_page/yaml](https://repo.ros2.org/status_page/yaml). For `rclcpp` in `ros_humble_default.yaml`:

```
rclcpp:
  build_status:
    ubuntu:
      jammy:
        amd64:
          build: 16.0.4-2jammy.20230426.055957
          main: 16.0.4-2jammy.20230426.055957
          test: 16.0.4-2jammy.20230426.055957
        source:
          build: 16.0.4-2jammy
          main: 16.0.4-2jammy
          test: 16.0.4-2jammy
  maintainers:
    ...
```

This doesn't link to any jobs per se, but if your question is really just:

> How can I see what binaries are available for a ROS2 package?

combining the information from all three `.yaml`s for Humble would seem to answer that.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2023-05-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chives_onion](https://answers.ros.org/users/39292/chives_onion/) on 2023-05-25**:
I was indeed just looking for available binaries, but your answer will help me track releases more closely. Thank you much!